# In Git-annex, what does "disable/enable expiry after X days" mean?

Tags: git-annex

Git-annex assistant configuration has an item saying "disable/enable expiry after X days". What does it mean? Am I the only one confused by this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are refering to the `/config/unused` section of the webapp, correct? If so, let me paste the rest of this page:

> **Managing unused files**
>
> Old versions of files and deleted files can be
>   preserved inside this repository.
>
> This might be useful, if you ever need to access those old or deleted
>   files. But they'll also use up disk space. There are three ways to
>   deal with this.
>
> 1. Set up a backup or archive repository, on a removable drive or in the
>      cloud, and the unused files will be moved to it, freeing up space.
>      `[Add a new repository]`
> 2. Or, you can let unused files expire after a period of time.
>
>    `[disable expiry] after [7] days. [Save Changes]`
> 3. Finally, you can clean up all unused files
>      manually at any time.
>
>    `[Clean up unused files now]`

So basically, the is the web interface for automatic purging of [unused data](https://git-annex.branchable.com/walkthrough/unused_data/). This can happen for example when you doing `git rm` without first doing `git annex drop` on the file. It also happens when you modify a file (with `git annex edit`).